# Dynamic programming for selecting strategy

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say there are two arrays:

```
a[] = a_1, a_2, ..., a_n
b[] = b_1, b_2, ..., b_m
```

And there is a set `s` contains `(a_i, b_j)` pairs, in this set, we need to find maximum number of pairs that there are no two pair `(a_i, b_j)` and  `(a_i', b_j')` satisfy that `i'<i && j'<j`.

So, `(a_2, b_1)`, `(a_3, b_2)` are not allowed to be selected together while `(a_1, b_2)` and `(a_2, b_1)`, `(a_1, b_2)` and `(a_3, b_2)` are fine.

For example, the set is `{(a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2), (a_2, b_1), (a_3, b_2)}`
We need to pick `(a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2), (a_2, b_1)` for selecting 3 pairs.

It seems that a dp algorithm is needed to be built, right? Do you have any hint for it? Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example as well, the question is not that clear to me. Also how a_2 and a_1 is in the set 1 is not greater than 2, right

Comment: Hi @zenwraight we don't allow i'<i && j'<j, so a_2 and a_1 are fine while a_2 has  b_1 and a_1 has b_2. Moreover, in another example { (a_2, b_1), (a_3, b_2), (a_3, b_3),}, all of them are fine

Comment: Ohk got it, it was not clear that which condition is allowed. Can you update the question again with a note that this is the condition which is not allowed

Comment: I'm not an expert but this looks to me like a maximum clique problem, which is supposedly NP-complete. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be reduced to the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) by ordering the a_i by i decreasing and b_j by j increasing (on equality of i). This would give a solution with complexity O(NlogN), where N is the number of entries in the set.

Example: `{(a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2), (a_2, b_1), (a_3, b_2)}`

Ordered: `{(a_3, b_2), (a_2, b_1), (a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2)}`

Longest increasing subsequence of j: `{b_1, b_1, b_2}`, entries at indexes `{1, 2, 3}`

Solution: `{(a_2, b_1), (a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2)}`

Comment: I looks good @maraca but could you come up with any idea with O(mn), which could be more stable?

Comment: The sort could be optimized using counting or radix sort. But I don't think you can improve the algorithm for the longest increasing subsequence. If N is the number of entries in the set and a and b are of the same length n, then O(nm) = O(n^2) and max N is n^2 too, which would give worst performance of O(n^2logn^2) for the algorithm above. Not that much worse.

Comment: I just found a counterexample of it @maraca ,  what if the `(a_3, b_2)` is `(a_3, b_0)`. The sorted set will be `{(a_3, b_0), (a_2, b_1), (a_1, b_1), (a_1, b_2)}`, and according to your alg, the whole set is valid, but actually `a_3 > a_2` while `b_0 < b_1`. Furthermore, in another example, `(a_5, b_6), (a_4, b_5), (a_3, b_4)`, the alg will give result 1, but the whole set is valid.

Comment: Well then we understand the problem differently. For me both your examples are correct. i > i' and j < j' is no violation of NOT (i < i' and j < j') while in your second example all possible pairs violate it.